# Searching through Encrypted data in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption, aes

So I've been searching about the possibility of searching the encrypted data that are stored in my database. I'm implementing a new system that requires encryption for some columns (Private date like name, email and so on). Some of those encrypted data can be used while searching for customer information. For instance, the user can search for a customer by his name, mobile, email and etc.. These data are encrypted in the database using AES encryption method. After spending so many hours on searching about the best possible way of doing the search I came up empty handed. So I though of doing this in a way that can fulfill my purpose. The way I handled that is by doing the following:

1. Reading all the columns for the required search table into a DataSet
2. Going through each an every encrypted column and decrypt it using the decryption function
3. Appending the decrypted values to the Dataset
4. Reading all the values (All values are in plain test) from the DataSet into a DataView
5. Applying the filter (Search criteria) to the DataView
6. Databind the GridView to display the result in plain text

I know that the above process is consuming the memory and processor because each time a search button is clicked I have to read and decrypt all the values from a specific table and then apply the filter to get the final output. Now it takes about 6 seconds or more to get the result for only around 20 records.

So my question is, what do you guys suggest? and is there any other better way for doing such thing? And how do Facebook for example handle such a requirement since you can search by the name or email address (and I believe those should be encrypted in their database)

Your help and suggestions are highly appreciated

Comment: is it really necessary to encrypt ALL user data?

Comment: I think is better to handle encrypt data at dbms side, for example with SQL Server 2016 you can use "Always Encrypted": https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt163865.aspx

Comment: @numX: I'm trying to protect the customer's private data and follow the standards for encryption because it is an online system.

Comment: @StefanoBalzarotti I choose not to use the SQL Server encryption as it is going tone an online system and I will not have full control of the SQL Server therefore I will not have a control over the Service Master Key (The system is going to be hosted on a third party hosting service at the beginning). So When changing the hosting provider in the future that will cause an issue for my stored data

Comment: You may want to look at **homomorphic** encryption. But beware, you'll venture into academic level papers pretty fast.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I went through your suggestion but as you mentioned I couldn't find any C# working implementation. Thanks for the suggestion though